# Click counter without javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using this javascript for a click counter in my blogger blog:

```
    function clickCounter() {
if(typeof(Storage) !== &quot;undefined&quot;) {
    if (sessionStorage.clickcount) {
        sessionStorage.clickcount = Number(sessionStorage.clickcount)+1;
    } else {
        sessionStorage.clickcount = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById(&quot;result&quot;).innerHTML = &quot;Correct! &quot; + sessionStorage.clickcount + &quot; Smart answers &#39;til now.&quot;;
} else {
    document.getElementById(&quot;result&quot;).innerHTML = &quot;Sorry, your browser does not support this quiz...&quot;;
}
```

}

```
<button onclick="clickCounter()" type="button">Suspension</button>
```

Is there any way to create something similar through a non javascript method?

Can you help me triger an event (extra text message through popup or within the page) every 5, 10, 20, 100 clicks?

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you have the ability to have a server side solution?  Outside of that I am not sure it's possible.

Comment: No server side solution for me Brad. Thank you for asking.

Comment: So you want to manipulate the DOM without JS. Good luck.

Comment: Well Alon actually i was hoping more in some idea out of the box. Something from the scratch let's say. Not really manipulating the existing code.

Comment: @user3686107 Read Jeremy's answer - It explain exactly the limitation you're facing and why it's probably impossible to achieve (Unless you have JS and/or server side)

Comment: Yes Alon i agree. That's cristal clear. Thank you Jeremy and all of you for the collaboration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML, and the Web in general, was designed to be stateless.

When you pull up a page, it should be like the first time -- and every time -- you pull up the page.

Since then, people have come up with a number of techniques to add state -- to save data, but they all involved one of two methods -- or sometimes both.

*Method 1: Store state on the server.*

This method uses HTML forms or cookies to slip information to the server when you load and reload a page.

*Method 2: Store state in the client*

While there are some older versions of Internet Explorer that can be coded in VBA, we are going to ignore that.  The only "real" way to run any kind of code on the client, to store any data, is to use JavaScript.

*Method 3: Use the client to talk to the server*

Using Ajax, you can let your client talk to the server, but without doing a page reload.  This still uses JavaScript.

So, to answer your question:

- Without a server
- Without JavaScript

No, you cannot save or store anything.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this but...

What if you put multiple buttons positioned on top of each other. As each one is clicked, it can be made to vanish with something like

```
a:visited { display: none; }
```

The ones that need to display a message (5th, 10th, etc.) have different behavior attached.

See [on click hide this (button link) pure css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318248/on-click-hide-this-button-link-pure-css)

Comment: Genius! (though probably impractical).  Well done with a "non-javascript" solution none the less.

Comment: Thank you bmb that gave me a lot of ideas for other situations but what i forgot to mention regarding extra events when a certain number i reached is that clicks come from buttons in different pages and the result is shown in one div <div id="result"></div> at the top of the website. What i would really like is to have an extra event when the "result reaches 5, 10 etc.

Comment: I agree with JonSG, for any practical situation, this probably doesn't work. Jeremy's answer is more correct, although mine is an example of the client (sort of) storing something without javascript. Unfortunately, you can't *retrieve* that something. I'm upvoting Jeremy.