# Pure CSS toggle display conflicting with native CSS

Tags: html, css

The situation is as follows:

I want to toggle display of two HTML items with pure CSS.

In particular, display two different language contents with a pure CSS toggle.

After dealing with CSS's weird things, I finally got this (working fiddle below):

##### HTML

```html
<span class="spanEN" tabindex="0">EN</span>
<span class="spanES" tabindex="0">ES</span>
<div class="EN" >Some ENGLISH content</div>
<div class="ES" >Some SPANISH content</div>
```

##### CSS

```css
.spanEN:focus ~ .ES {
  display: none;
}
.spanEN:focus ~ .EN {
  display: block;
}
.spanES:focus ~ .EN {
  display: none;
}
.spanES:focus ~ .ES {
  display: block;
}
.ES {
  display: none;
}
```

The problem is that after migrating that to my site (hosted in Wordpress.com), it's no longer working.

**This is due to the removal of tabindex property when saving the content.**

I was also trying to reproduce the same behaviour by using `<a>` tags like in this question: [on click hide this (button link) pure css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318248/on-click-hide-this-button-link-pure-css)

But I haven't been able to do it. Any idea will be appreciated.

P.S.: `<style scoped>` cannot be used for targeting this HTML block.

**Edit:** I found out thanks to the comments that the tabindex="0" is being removed from the HTML when saving. Any idea on how to solve this? Or any workaround that won't require the tabindex attribute to be used? Editing question accordingly.

**Working JS Fiddle here (in case inline example doesn’t work)**: http://jsfiddle.net/6W7XD/5348/

```css
.spanEN:focus ~ .ES {
  display: none;
}
.spanEN:focus ~ .EN {
  display: block;
}
.spanES:focus ~ .EN {
  display: none;
}
.spanES:focus ~ .ES {
  display: block;
}
.ES {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="spanEN" tabindex="0">EN</span>
<span class="spanES" tabindex="0">ES</span>
<div class="EN" >Some ENGLISH content</div>
<div class="ES" >Some SPANISH content</div>
```

Comment: it would be helpful if we could see the site where it doesn't work.

Comment: Make sure the `<span>` and `<div>` are siblings, so that `~` can work.

Comment: Wordpress could be changing the HTML...it often wraps elements in `<p>` tags for some unholy reason. Without seeing the ACTUAL code *not working* in place, there's not much we can do.

Comment: Sorry for such a late response. And thanks for your tips.

I found out what the problem is, but I haven't found a solution yet.

The tabindex="0" is being removed from the HTML when saving.

If I add it with the element inspector on the original website, it works.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using [!important](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqimportn.htm)?

If you haven't, you can try this

```css
.spanEN:focus ~ .ES {
  display: none !important;
}
.spanEN:focus ~ .EN {
  display: block !important;
}
.spanES:focus ~ .EN {
  display: none !important;
}
.spanES:focus ~ .ES {
  display: block !important;
}
.ES {
  display: none ;
}
```