# How to hide this button using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

We are using a .Net web application from a vendor. It has a feature for user to enter JavaScript and CSS for performing some simple UI modification. They are executed when loading the application.

We want to hide a button on the web UI temporary.

[image]

In F12 developer tools, we found the id for that button.

[image]

We used this CSS script to hide the button and it works.

```
#ext-gen391 {
display: none !important;}
```

However, the id is not fixed. It changes with different groups of login users. So that CSS script is not good enough.

I am thinking of using JavaScript but not sure how to start. Can someone help?

**Edit:**
Thanks everyone for the input. Sorry that I did not mention that other buttons have the id starts with ext-gen too.

It seems to me that the only "unique identity" I can refer to is the button's position.

[image]

How to hide that 3rd td element? Take note that the id ext-gen391 is not fixed. It will be different for different groups of login users.

Comment: Looks like an application that usese ExtJS. Unless  you can convice the vendor to give the elements proper IDs, it will be difficult to find the right one.

Comment: You'll need to find some aspect that identifies the button even if the id changes. Is it the only one that starts with "ext-gen"? Is it always the first button in the toolbar? Is it the only one with the `x-toolbar-cell` class?

Comment: A mistake in the code. It should be #ext-gen391, not .ext-gen391. It is updated

Comment: It is not the only button that starts with ext-gen. Yes, it is always the first button in that part of toolbar (right end). No, it is not the only one with the  x-toolbar-cell class

Comment: @ammoQ Do you mean there is another ID that we can only get it from the developer, and not able to find it from F12 developer tools?

Comment: @user605179 In ExtJS, you can give specific IDs to each element; if you do not, ExtJS will generate unpredictable IDs.

Answer (score 0):

First off that small snippet of CSS you have tries to select the button based on a class not an Id. Which is why it doesn't work.

You could use CSS

```
[id^=ext-gen] {
   display: none !important;
}
```

or jQuery

```
$('[id^=ext-gen]').hide();
```

but, really, the best way if you have control over what gets rendered you should try and add a more unique id/class instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an id matcher like this in the css:

```
*[id^="ext-gen"] {

}
```

To select all the HTML elements that ahve an id that starts with ext-gen.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
td.x-toolbar-cell[id^=ext-gen]{
    display: none !important;
}
```

if only the number changes, see [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

try you use css class name to do that.

You could solve it by putting your Open link inside the #show div

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/kkpBb/4/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="show">
    <a href="#show" id="open" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Open</a>
    <div id="content">
        some text...
        <a href="#hide" id="close" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#content {
    display: none;
}
#show:target #content {
    display: inline-block;
}
#show:target #open {
    display: none;
}
```

This solution was used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318248/on-click-hide-this-button-link-pure-css). 
Congratulations [@Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3354957/mathias)