# Hiding a link on click css only

Tags: html, css

i'm pretty new to coding (just started a free weeks ago with html and css). For a news page i tried to implement "read on" links, similiar to this question here: [on click hide this (button link) pure css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318248/on-click-hide-this-button-link-pure-css)

However i can't seem to make the link disappear after clicking it. 
I got this for my code so far (opening and closing works just fine):

```css
.readmore {
  display: none;
}

article[id*="n"]:target .readmore {
  display: block;
}

article:target .used {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<article>Text visible after you open the site.


  <a href="#n2" class="used">Link that opens more text and should diappear after clicking</a>

  <article id="n2">
    <div class="readmore">more text
     <a href="#back">Closing button</a>
    </div>
  </article>
</article>
```

I feel like i messed something up big time, but i really can't figure it out.

Comment: `:target` matches an element with the id of the URL's fragment, but that element (`#n2`) has no children `.used`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put your link inside the article tag including your id.

```css
.readmore {
  display: none;
}

article[id*="n"]:target .readmore {
  display: block;
}

article[id*="n"]:target .used {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<article>Text visible after you open the site.

  <article id="n2">
    <a href="#n2" class="used">Link that opens more text and should diappear after clicking</a>
    <div class="readmore">more text
      <a href="#back">Closing button</a>
    </div>
  </article>
</article>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using this you can achieve what you want.....you have added id inner article which you have to give parent artical and change css

```
.readmore {
  display: none;
}

#n2:target .readmore {
  display: block;
}

#n2:target .used {
  display: none;
}
```

```css
.readmore {
  display: none;
}

#n2:target .readmore {
  display: block;
}

#n2:target .used {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<article id="n2">Text visible after you open the site.


  <a href="#n2" class="used">Link that opens more text and should diappear after clicking</a>

  <article>
    <div class="readmore">more text
     <a href="#back">Closing button</a>
    </div>
  </article>
</article>
```

Comment: You should explain what the problem was, and what you did to solve it

Comment: @RicardoRibeiro yes sure

Comment: better use the same selectors for all the article, as used in question. `#n2` is just for one id.